# Tensorflow confusion matrix for multiclass classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

Thanks for your help. I am coding a multiclass binary classifier for facial actions (such as raised eyebrow, parted lips), and I want to make a confusion matrix. There are 6 facial actions and 593 samples. I'm getting this error: I'm getting this error: "Shape (?, 2, 6) must have rank 2". From documentation, tf.confusion_matrix takes 1-D vectors, but I think there should be a way to shape the input data from the feed_dict so that it works, based on [Tensorflow Confusion Matrix in TensorBoard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617463/tensorflow-confusion-matrix-in-tensorboard). The labels and predictions look like:

```
# Rows are samples, columns are classes, and the classes shows a facial
# action which is either 1 for detection or 0 for no detection. 
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],...]
```

I'm using a feed-forward MLP and the variable 'pred' is the prediction, with a threshold forcing a choice of 0 or 1. I tried multiplying predictions and labels by np.arange(1,7) to have the positive values match the indices but I got stuck on the shape of the arguments.

There's more code, but I'm showing what I think is relevant.

```
sess = tf.Session()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input], name = "x")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_output], name = "labels")

#2 fully connected layers
fc1 = fc_layer(x, n_input, n_hidden_1, "fc1")
relu = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
tf.summary.histogram("fc1/relu", relu)
logits = fc_layer(relu, n_hidden_1, n_output, "fc2")

# Calculate loss function
with tf.name_scope("xent"):
    xent = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=logits, labels=y, name="xent"))

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(xent)


# Choose between 0 and 1
onesMat = tf.ones_like(logits)
zerosMat = tf.zeros_like(logits)   
pred = tf.cast(tf.where(logits>=zero,onesMat,zerosMat),dtype=tf.float32, name = "op_to_restore")

# Problem occurs when I add this line. 
confusion = tf.confusion_matrix(predictions = pred*np.arange(1,7), labels = y*np.arange(1,7), num_classes = n_output, name = "confusion")

# Save and visualize results
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(init)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR + hparam + '/train')
writer.add_graph(sess.graph)


# Train
for i in range(2001):
    if i % 5 == 0:
      [train_accuracy, s] = sess.run([accuracy, summ], feed_dict={x: train_x, y: train_y})
      writer.add_summary(s, i)
    if i % 50 == 0:
      [acc,s] = sess.run([accuracy, summ],feed_dict={x: test_x, y: test_y})
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: train_x, y: train_y})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem as yours. I made use of the **argmax function** which fixed my problem.

Try this piece of code (or similiar):

```
cm = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=tf.argmax(y*np.arange(1,7), 1), predictions=tf.argmax(pred*np.arange(1,7)))

#then check the result:
with tf.Session() as sess:
    cm_reachable = cm.eval()
    print(cm_reachable)
```

And check out this detailed instruction:
[Tensorflow confusion matrix using one-hot code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810573/tensorflow-confusion-matrix-using-one-hot-code?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Not working anymore with tensorflow 2.15.0, getting the following error AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'confusion_matrix'